# Почему выдает ошибку в Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Делаю регистрацию по учебнику. Не совсем понимаю, как работают эти строчки, но ошибка из-за них.

```
if(!$row) {
  return back()->withErrors('Ссылка восстановления пароля устарела');
}
```

Ошибка:
`Undefined variable: row`

Весь код:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\User;

class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
    
    public function form($token, $email){
        return view('auth.reset-password', compact('token', 'email'));
    }

    public function reset(Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email|exists:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);

        $expire = Carbon::now()->subMinute(60);
        DB::table('password_resets')->where([
            'email' => $request->email,
            'token' => $request->token,
        ])->first();
        
        // если ссылка уже устарела, то ничего не делаем
        if(!$row) {
            return back()->withErrors('Ссылка восстановления пароля устарела');
        }

        User::where('email',  $request->email)->update(['password' => Hash::make($request->password)]);

        DB::table('passowrd_resets')->where(['email' =>$request->email])->delete();

        return redirect()->route('auth.login')->with('success', 'Ваш пароль изменен');
    }
}
```

Comment: видимо надо его получить как-то так `$row =  DB::table('password_resets')...`

Comment: да и $expire  по идее должен во where попасть, иначе он нигде не проверяется